# Compact mathematical expression

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Make a mathematical expression
whose value is equal to 2 that
uses all the digits 0, 1, 2, ... 9
exactly once and uses as few other
mathematical symbols as possible.

Comment: Which mathematical symbols are allowed?

Comment: @bobble All mathematical symbols are allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As hinted by @Will Octagon Gibson

> A solution not utilising any symbols would use only exponentiation. The easiest solution of this form would be $2^{13456789^0}$ (proof that exponentiation does not utilise symbols can be [found here](https://xkcd.com/2283/))

Alternatively,

> A quick brute force solution gives the following examples using only one symbol (I found a total of 48 solutions of this form):

> 26970/13485

> 53814/26907

> 97302/48651 etc.

Comment: Nice!  Now try doing it with NO additional symbols (just the 10 digits).

Comment: Well done. Could also have been any tower of powers staring by 2^1^(...^...)

Answer (score 2):

With no additional symbols, but a bit ugly:

> $1^{34567890}2$

Comment: In fact there are too many other solutions e.g. $134^{0^56789}2$.